# Is it possible to interact with the routing tree in a deployed Angular app? (Power BI/Angular)

Tags: angular, powerbi

My organisation uses Power BI to display various reports, and shares them to senior leaders with a [Power BI app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-create-distribute-apps). The other day someone asked if it was possible to search the reports in the app (there are currently dozens), and as Microsoft don’t provide a solution, I said no. However, I’ve privately started looking into my own solution, partly because I’m just interested.

Power BI apps seem to build themselves using Angular. One of the features of BI dashboard is a “web tile” that lets you embed code, including JavaScript. My plan of attack is to use this tile to somehow query the routing tree and link out to various reports within the content area.

My current problem is how I can replicate links like the ones in the nav bar, that change what appears in the content area. All my normal links open in a new tab rather than in the content area.

[A Power BI app, showing navigation and content areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd3Dr.png).

The furthest I’ve got is using `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()` in Chrome Devtools, then using the Event Listener to track down an example element that navigates in the content area when you click it. I can see this element pulls data from the view model with `{{viewModel.href}}`, and when I use `angular.element($0).scope()` I can see there’s an “action” object with routing information.

[An inspected navigational `li` element, with its `scope()` in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og4Bn.png)

Unfortunately this is where my rudimentary JavaScript and knowledge of web apps runs out, and I don’t quite know where to go next. I don’t fully understand how this even works, let alone replicating it in my own code.

So, given that I’m trying to extend the functionality of a deployed Angular app, is it possible for me to utilise its routing tree, allowing me to open things in the app content area?